# adding new dependency to a package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry this is probably a stupid questions...

I've downloaded and successfully built the mrpt_common, mrpt_slam, and mrpt_hwdrivers packages.  I assume this now allows me to reference some, if not all, MRPT functionality in a ros package.

However, when I add a reference to a mrpt class and add the include it get errors.

So now I'm wondering whether doing rosmake --rosdep-install  doesn't resolve things.

Can someone help me out?  My goal is to be able to reference and use any of the many useful MRPT classes from within a ROS package.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11525/adding-new-dependency-to-a-package/) by [Tim C](https://answers.ros.org/users/1028/tim-c/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-10-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
If I understand you in right way, you should open next file:

your_project_dir/manifest.xml

and add something like this:

Also, you can create new package with dependencies, e.g.

roscreate-pkg yourProjectName mrpt_common mrpt_slam mrpt_hwdrivers

After package name you should list all dependecies.
Hope this will be useful.

---

Originally posted by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) with karma: 546 on 2011-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

CaptainTrunky is right, you should just add one line to your manifest.xml.

But the **correct package to depend on** is `mrpt_libs`, which exports the required {c,l}flags. So it would be like:

`<depend package="mrpt_libs"/>`


Cheers!

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Blanco](https://answers.ros.org/users/2046/jose-luis-blanco/) with karma: 288 on 2012-03-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2